# Regular expression for MM-DD?

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't seem to find the regular expression for MM-DD anywhere. I already have the YYYY-MM-DD test in place here, I just need to replace it.

```
var date_regex = /^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/ ;
if(!(date_regex.test(beginDate)) || !(date_regex.test(endDate))) {
    util.popup.alert('Dates must be in "MM-DD" format.');
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the `[0-9]{4}-`, i.e. the `YYYY-` part from the start. Although I'm surprised that you're happy accepting years such as 9999

Comment: (9999 is a valid year.) Regex is great for validating *the format*, but use a date class/module/library to validate the date.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/ ;
```